# How do I set Fillfactor to 0 in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a set of indexes in my databases, and I would like to set the Fill Factor to 0. Some of these are currently set to 100. I know that as far as SQL Server is concerned, this is the same, but we have a piece of software which is comparing two databases with the same schema and it is detecting a difference between them if the Fill Factor of an index is 0 in one database and 100 in the other. This is a problem.

Whilst we go about updating our software to be a bit cleverer about this, I would like to be able to set the Fill Factor to 0 on various indexes. **SQL Server won't let you specify a Fill Factor of 0 (it must be 1..100),** so the only way I can think of doing this is to DROP the index and recreate it (with the server default set to 0).

But is there another (and preferably quicker) way?

Comment: Rather than drop/create, you can use `ALTER INDEX...REBUILD` or `CREATE INDEX...WITH(DROP_EXISTING=ON)` and specify the desired `FILLFACTOR`.

Comment: @DanGuzman I should have mentioned that you cannot specify a FIll Factor of 0 (I've updated the question). I tried ALTER INDEX...REBUILD (without specifying one at all), and it didn't change the fill factor. ). But CREATE INDEX WITH(DROP_EXISTING=ON) might work if I don't specify a fill factor.

Comment: I seem to recall that this is actually an "error" made by some scripting tools/libraries -- maybe a version of SSMS, maybe AMO -- where they proactively "translate" 0 to 100 (or vice versa). See also: adding or removing parentheses from `CHECK` constraints. If this memory isn't failing me, then you are much better off compensating for this fact by improving your tooling, since you can expect it to keep happening, and rebuilding indexes ain't cheap. Doubly so if you're not on Enterprise and can't rebuild them online. If you're doing this on empty databases it's less of an issue, of course.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Fixing the tooling is of course the right thing to do, but that will take time, and I need to help my client now.

Comment: @bornfromanegg, I did a quick test and `CREATE INDEX ... WITH(DROP_EXISTING=ON)` with the `fill factor (%)`  conf option set to zero and it did honor the system default. That should be much more efficient than the drop/create.

Comment: @DanGuzman: I'm confused, how is `DROP_EXISTING = ON` different from `DROP` followed by `CREATE`, other than the atomicity? In both cases the index is entirely rebuilt and so the efficiency is the same, right?

Comment: @JeroenMostert, `DROP/CREATE` will recreate the index from scratch. In the case of the clustered index, the DROP will rebuild all the non-clustered indexes to change the row locator from clustered index key to RID and the CREATE will do the reverse. `DROP_EXISTING = ON` leverages the existing index sort order and structure while allowing one to add/remove index keys and tweak options like fillfactor in the process. Non-clustered indexes are not touched in the case of the clustered index.

Comment: @DanGuzman: Oh, right. I forgot we're talking about the clindex specifically -- turning your table into a heap is not a good idea, even if temporarily. :P

Comment: @JeroenMostert, `DROP_EXISTING = ON` will be faster for non-clustered indexes too since it eliminates the sort.

Comment: @DanGuzman: definitely getting OT now (so I'll shut up after this one) but would that still hold for a heavily fragmented index, where using the clustered index as a basis might actually be better (assuming that's not fragmented)?

Comment: @JeroenMostert, with extreme external fragmentation on the non-clustered index and spinning media, maybe the sort for the non-clustered build could be faster than reading the existing index in key order but I doubt it. The speed of the sort would also depend on memory size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the default instance `fill factor (%)` configuration value is set to zero, you can omit `FILLBACTOR` and recreate indexes with `CREATE INDEX...WITH (DROP_EXISTING=ON)`. This will be a bit more efficient than DROP/CREATE because no sort will be needed to recreate the index and, the case of the clustered index, non-clustered indexes won't need to be rebuilt twice.